# textInput library leak

Tags: objective-c, xcode, memory-leaks

I profile my below leak project .I can't find my leaked Code ,buf find the apple Library leak.

the profile result is below.and the code is on git hub.

```
Leaked Object   #   Address         Size            Responsible Library 
Malloc 16 Bytes 1   0xa9b6870   16 Bytes    TextInput   
[TIResourcePathManager          
fetchAssetsWithNames:forInputModes:updatingDictionary:continuation:]_block_invoke_0
```

how to deal the apple lib leak?

is it only exist in simulator,not device?

before some body ever find the problem.

https://github.com/piaoapiao/leak

Comment: The simulator is not a good way to test memory leaks. It's not uncommon to see leaks in the simulator that don't exist on a real device. Do all of your profiling on a real device. Real users won't be using the simulator.

Comment: how to profile  on real device ?

Comment: The same way except build against a real device instead of the simulator.

Answer (score 0):

Yes i found the same leak messages base on device.